# Install multiple Tampermonkey Scripts

Tags: tampermonkey

is there any way how I can offer the option on my website, that the user can install multiple scripts with one click?

I am maintaining my code in several scripts because they have different functions or working on different sub domains in our intranet.

When my colleagues are changing the computer, chrome will install the tampermonkey add-on but not the scripts. That's why they will have to install them after every change of their place (it's happening often, because were using "hot desking" in our company).

I am offer the download with this source:

```
<a href="scripts/btb.website.user.js">Website</a><br />
<a href="scripts/btb.language.user.js">Language Lines</a><br />
<a href="scripts/btb.alpha.user.js">Phonetic Alphabet</a><br />
<button id="install">Install</button>
```

I want to to add a button to install all scripts at the same time.
I tried something like this:

```
$('#install').click(function(){
    $('a').click();
});
```

but it is not working. actually nothing is happening :(

Do you have any suggestions how I can simplify the installation process of the scripts? The links above are only a part of it. The total amount is about 10-15 scripts and clicking everyone one by one is very annoying :/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do they have separate Chrome user-profiles?  If so, then they can sync the profiles across different machines and the scripts will carry over.  If not, then no; Each script must be installed separately.  It would be a security and performance risk otherwise.

Comment: We have cooperate Google accounts. As I said, the addons are syncing, but only the addons. The scripts for tamper monkey are not installed after the sync

Comment: That's either a bug in Tampermonkey or a configuration error in your system(s).  Look into Tampermonkey syncing as it's the best way.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder on the build-in function. I tried it once with TESLA but it was not working for me. I will play around with the option again. Is it really necessary to activate this option every time when the people change the computer? Is there a possibility to have already activated after the installation of the add-on through the sync of Chrome?

Comment: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.org